# select any item from a list of 10,000 items in android

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

I try to search through the questions to see if there is any similar thread to my problem but so far haven't found any. 
Here is my problem is: I have a list of products which contains ~10,000 items stored in a SQLite db. In my app, I need to search for any item from this list. I have a few options:

- Use the autoCompleteTextView, with all products preloaded, and as I type the product's name, the list will suggest the product, hence I just need to select from the suggestion. This is the simplest way but I feel 10,000 items (or even more in the future) would be very heavy to load
- As I type any character and click search, the app will do a select all products from the db with the character as a filter. The result set is then fed to some list view so that i can pick any item. This approach would save the memory as the app won't load all items to the memory but only items that contain the filtering characters.

Is there any better way to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second option is the best way. Its similar to how you get a list of recommended search results while you type in your query. For you, assuming your using asynctask to query your db you can have a proper loading message signaled by onProgressUpdate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean something similar to google instant search ? If that is the case then the query is made any moment I type any character, isn't it ?

Comment: and btw, i'm quite new to android, so could you pls elaborate more about "For you, assuming your using asynctask to query your db you can have a proper loading message signaled by onProgressUpdate" tks

Comment: First, if your new to android ASyncTask should be your best friend. The docs for it on google's site are very clear and provide an example. its the best way to handle multiple threads in android, and provides a mechanism to report the progress on the background thread. The query would be made as soon as someone types a letter, but still with asynctask it wont bog the app down.

Comment: you can also use asynctask to partially load your list, and when the user scrolls down to the end of 20 or so items it loads more. Google voice and other apps do this rather well.

Comment: Thanks, the ASyncTask sounds interesting, I will read up that part soon :)

Comment: could you accept an answer if you find it satisfactory? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you categorize the items? So that you can use use spinner to select the category, and use AutoCompleteTextView to type and select items.

Comment: unfortunately all items belong to the same category :|